# Insert Space Between string Google Map Autosuggest

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to insert space between in google map Autocomplete string right now like this it is coming

AllentownNJ
AllentownPA

My requirement is like this

Allentown NJ
Allentown PA

```
       predictionsDropDown.empty();
        $.each(predictions, function(i, prediction) {
        predictionsDropDown.append('<div>' + $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate(prediction.terms[0].value) + '</div>'   +'<div> &nbsp;' + $.fn.cityAutocomplete.transliterate(prediction.terms[1].value) + '</div>');

        });
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you @Rahul

Comment: I have used &nbsp; Check my updated code

Comment: Okay, I made it a bit more complicated than it actually was ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if the string is always build like this you could do sth like this:

```
var inputString = "AllentownNJ";
    var positions = [];
    for(var i=0; i<inputString.length; i++){
        if(inputString[i].match(/[A-Z]/) != null){
            positions.push(i);
        }
    }
    alert(positions[1]);

    var output = [inputString.slice(0, positions[1]), inputString.slice(positions[1])].join(' ');
    alert(output);
```

This will add a space before the second Uppercase letter is found in a string. Probably not the most elegant way to solve this, but it works.

Comment: thanks for suggestion I have used &nbsp; it's working